# Organizing data in report (rdlc)

Tags: visual-studio, sorting, report, rdlc, organization

I have sql query which shows me data in RDLC report. Query is not important for this purpose, so let's just say that I have table with name, city, country, company, phone number. I want to display list of all data, sort by country, but first only show country that begins with "A" then I want page break and on new page to "print" country with B and so on. There must be a proper way to do this but I don't know it.

Comment: Check the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356016/creating-hierarchical-custom-model-in-ssrs/45356460#45356460

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any connection and still can't find answer.

Comment: What you need is grouping. Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs and here is the tutorial on grouping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services
You can set your page break for group.

Comment: I know that, but how can I group by first letter?

Comment: Ah, I see what is the problem. I added answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To page break your report based on the first letter of the field only, first add group by your Country field, then click on Expression button (fx button) in group property:

[image]

and edit your grouping expression to be

`=Left(Fields!Country.Value, 1)`

And then set your page break in "Page Break" tab:

[image]

Comment: I have already tried with '=Left(Fields!Country.Value, 1)' but didn't succeed but this method works perfectly. Thank you very much. :) This is off course right and perfect answer.